# Introspection of Objective-C objects properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, oop, introspection

**Is it possible to programmatically get the properties of an object in objective-c without using the runtime methods?** I only ask because it seems unnecessary to check it at runtime, when it won't be changing. 
I'm thinking of something to this effect:

```
MyObject *foo = [[MyObject alloc] init];
NSDictionary *propertiesNamesAndValues = [foo getAllProperties];
```

Currently my solution looks like this:

```
id currentClass = [MyObject class];
NSString *propertyName;
unsigned int outCount, i;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(currentClass, &outCount);
for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) 
{
    objc_property_t property = properties[i];
    propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property)];
    NSLog(propertyName);
    NSLog(@"%@",[foo valueForKey:propertyName]);
}
```

Comment: So you basically want a wrapper around that code called `getAllProperties`? Why not just add that code in a category on `NSObject`?

Comment: That `NSDictionary *propertiesNamesAndValues = [foo getAllProperties];` would be executed at runtime just as much as your current solution. Like @mattjgalloway says, it looks like you're just asking if you can encapsulate that functionality in a method, and the answer is yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer is *no*.

Introspection by definition happens at runtime. 
Additionally, objective-c is highly dynamic language deferring virtually everything to runtime.

In Objective-C, you just don't have that much syntactic sugar for introspection - you just have plain-C runtime functions.

However, nothing stops you from writing some categories on `NSObject` to provide more Objective-C'ish API and I guess there must be some open source implementations already over internet.